# Is this package dependency conflict with liberation-fonts a bug?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dependencies, dnf

Google's google-chrome-stable requires the following dependency:

```
liberation-fonts 1:2.00.5-3.fc30 updates
```

Fedora's Wine package requires the following dependency:

```
liberation-narrow-fonts 1.07.6-1.fc30 fedora
```

I now have a dependency problem when trying to perform an update:

```
 Problem: cannot install both liberation-fonts-1:2.00.5-1.fc30.noarch and liberation-fonts-1:2.00.5-3.fc30.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package liberation-narrow-fonts-1.07.6-1.fc30.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package liberation-fonts-1:2.00.5-3.fc30.noarch
```

The suggested `--best --allowerasing` options don't solve this:

```
$ sudo yum update --best --allowerasing -y
Last metadata expiration check: 0:09:08 ago on Sun 01 Sep 2019 06:37:49 PM EDT.
Error: 
 Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package liberation-fonts-1:2.00.5-3.fc30.noarch
  - cannot install both liberation-fonts-1:2.00.5-1.fc30.noarch and liberation-fonts-1:2.00.5-3.fc30.noarch
  - problem with installed package liberation-narrow-fonts-1.07.6-1.fc30.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package liberation-narrow-fonts-1.07.6-1.fc30.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

I believe this is due to `liberation-fonts` including fonts which are also present in `liberation-narrow-fonts`, but this is a guess.

I understand that `google-chrome-stable` is not part of the official repositories but both font packages are. Considering that these packages are conflicting, is this a problem with `google-chrome-stable` or with Fedora's package management?

Is this a local problem or something that should be reported upstream?

I am using Fedora 30 x86_64.

Comment: Try chromium - it doesn't have these dependencies.

Comment: @ajgringo619: Same problem with Chromium. Not sure why you were downvoted for this.

Comment: My bad: I think it might be LibreOffice vs Wine in my case (as opposed to Chromium). Either way, seems to be a common issue - also saw a post about this on Reddit.

Comment: Looks like several bug reports have been filed as well, _e.g._ see [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1747737) and [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1747785).

Comment: I'm getting same with different versions:  "Problem: cannot install both liberation-fonts-1:2.00.5-1.fc30.noarch and liberation-fonts-1:2.00.5-3.fc30.noarch"

Comment: The problem fixed itself for me now; looks like WINE has issued updates for the relevant packages.